# how to pass a Parameter from a Method which opens a UIAlertView to the UIAlertViewDelegate-Method?

Tags: iphone, key, uialertview

Given the following code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (mainViewController.loggedIn) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"notification received. view now?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" otherButtonTitles: @"Show"), nil];
        NSString *hash = [userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];

        [alert setValue:hash forKey:@"hash"];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Here I try to set a value (hash) for the key @"hash". I'm doing this, because I need this hash value in case the user presses the "Show" button. Then - in the delegate method - I try to read the value again:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *hash = [alertView valueForKey:@"hash"];
        if (hash != nil) {
            // send hash to server to show the correct site
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as i call`[alert setValue:hash forKey:@"hash"];` my iphone app crashes.
This is what i see in the console:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hash.'

Does anybody has an idea what I made wrong. Or how could i pass my "hash" value to the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method?

Comment: Just declare hash as NSString global variable and change it when you want, you can't call setValue on an alertView.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `hash` as NSString class member. While you are showing the alertview, set the `hash` variable. Also, set a `tag` to the alertview.

In `clickedButtonAtIndex` method, check the alertview tag and use the `hash` value if required.